# Ugly font with QOwnNotes

Tags: debian, fonts, qt

I have a very bad font. I think it's a Qt issue. I installed a Qownnotes snap on Debian Sid. I'm new to snap's and Qt and I can't find a explanation why this happens. When I see  the screenshot on the QOwnnotes website the font is very nice. I tried to change the font in ~/.fonts.conf but without any luck.

[screenshot QOwnnotes Ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrLBW.png)

[screenshot QOwnnotes Nice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIKo0.png)

**Update** I ask my colleague to install a snap with his Ubuntu PC. The font looks nice so it can't be a snap problem. So I think it must be a Qt like problem.

Comment: So, I installed this on Solus using their repo as well as the snap.  The one in the snap looked atrocious - almost unreadable bad.  The one from the repo looked just fine.  I think this must be something associated with the snap.